# Power Apps Studio - XMLHttpRequest error(string)

Tags: powerapps

I have an app with the Collaboration With Git Version Control features enabled.

As of a few days ago I can't open the studio.

The following error is displayed:

[image]

I tried creating a new Github token, but the error persists.

Please help!

```
WebAuthoring abnormal termination.
Client date/time: 2022-01-15T19:31:25.722Z
Version: 3.21123.25 (v3.21123.25.211215862)
Session ID: 72sadasd8c1528d77
description: {"exception":{"message":"XMLHttpRequest error(string). {\"traceLevel\":3,\"message\":\"An error occurred in Document API documentservicev2.completeloadfromgitasync, activity id b5193301-6734-4bfe-a3a1-d8d1d4a842b2\",\"status\":500}","name":"UnhandledError","_isCritical":true,"detail":{"exception":{}}},"error":"[circular]","promise":{"_oncancel":null,"_nextState":null,"_state":{"name":"error","enter":"[function]","cancel":"[function]","done":null,"then":null,"_completed":"[function]","_error":"[function]","_notify":"[function]","_progress":"[function]","_setCompleteValue":"[function]","_setErrorValue":"[function]"},"_listeners":null,"_value":"[circular]","_isException":false,"_errorId":17,"done":"[function]","then":"[function]"},"id":17,"setPromise":"[function]"}
stack: t@https://cdn-pwaprodweu.azureedge.net/v3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/git-version-control#known-limitations

Under known limitations: if you used components for example you can break your app.

Have you tried setting it back 1 or 2 versions and move on from there?

Comment: even if I go back to the non-Github version, the app asks for the GH credentials and breaks.